# Are modal views in their own windows in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, window, modal-view

I guess is a simple one to answer. When I call a view controller to be presented in a modal view, is it residing in its own window layer or is it just a view animated on top of the presenting view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find out yourself ;)

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myModalView recursiveDescription]);
```

Comment: I wish I knew about this a long time ago. This is only documented in a technical note. Thanks.